# How can i keep state in a React component using ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use a stateful React component with ES6 but when I define a constructor the constructor will only be called once while the component is rendered multiple times (from its parent). Example shown below.

```
class SubComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Creating sub component");
    this.state = { count: props.count };
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Rendering sub component", this.state.count);
    return (<div>count: {this.state.count}</div>);
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Creating app");
    this.state = { count: 0 };
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
    setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Rendering app", this.state.count);
    return (<SubComponent count={this.state.count} />);
  }
}
```

This will not update the rendered output (it will always be `count: 0`) but the logs will output:

```
Creating app
Rendering app 0
Creating sub component
Rendering sub component 0
Rendering app 1
Rendering sub component 0
Rendering app 2
Rendering sub component 0
Rendering app 3
Rendering sub component 0
...
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jor0xu1a/1/

I'm aware that the example `SubComponent` doesn't need a state but I tried making it as simple as possible to show my problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to read [Props in getInitialState Is an Anti-Pattern](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html).

Basically, as few components as possible should have state. As the other answers already said, in your case you can just use `this.props.count` to refer to the current value. There doesn't seem to be any reason why `SubComponent` should have its own state.

However, if you really want to compute the component's state from the props it receives, it is your responsibility to keep them in sync, with the life cycle method [`componentWillReceiveProps`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({count: nextProps.count});
}
```

Comment: I would have posted my answer here if I only had seen your post before :) Yeah, it was my mistake for believing that the parent always re-creates its children on re-render. `componentWillReceiveProps` solved my dilemma, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

In SubComponent it is `props` not state - change it to `this.props.count` and this will work

Answer (score 0):

You SubComponent should be:

```
 class SubComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Creating sub component");
      }

      render() {
        return (<div>count: {this.props.count}</div>);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I thought that the constructor (or `getInitialState` for ES5) is called whenever the component is being re-rendered by the parent (I thought that the parent 're-creates' its children on render) but that's not always the case. I should had read up on it ([url](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)) and tried it with ES5 ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26352/)) before thinking it was something I didn't understand with ES6 and creating a question here.

And yes, the example `SubComponent` should use `this.props` but my use case had actual stateful functionality in my real component. I created the example as I thought for some reason that the result weren't the expected outcome when using ES6 (but it was).

Thank you for you feedback!